# array to string conversion error in $this->encrypter->encrypt

Tags: octobercms

Whenever I try to log into https://mywebsite.com/backend/backend/auth/signin I get the following error:

[image]

I don't get that error when I was a username that doesn't exist nor do I get that error when I use a bad password for a user that doesn't exist - I only get that error when I login with a valid username / password combo.

From what I've been able to determine the error is happening when OctoberCMS is prepping the response to my successful login attempt. It's trying to set the cookies, including `admin_auth`. The problem with `admin_auth` is that OctoberCMS is setting it to an array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$eMtuod9M2j5L99MPSMYo3eaFgW4dfvmJ0KSY9RXhQMd0w1klrwqEm"
}
```

Comment: You mean this is a bug in a third party PHP product? Have you contacted [their forum](https://octobercms.com/forum) already, to know if it's a known issue, or one they will resolve?

Comment: @Code4R7 - https://octobercms.com/support mentions Stack Overflow. If they're not going to provide support on Stack Overflow then they shouldn't mention it. In any event, I  think I figured out the issue. Need to test it but I think https://github.com/octobercms/library/commit/09e859a13ee5663ee6cb6f0c02a4a97e09deefa7 should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Update to October CMS v1.1 via composer and your problems will go away ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me _how_ to properly upgrade. My composer.json currently has 1.0.443 for october/rain, october/system, october/backend and october/cms. Since it's requiring a specific version `composer update` won't work. I tried changing that to 1.0.460 and then doing `composer update` but now I'm getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nz5o.png . v1.1 won't work because it requires PHP 7.2 and this server is running 7.1. All I want to do is update an address via the UI. I don't want to spend a week upgrading the whole server and then testing every app on the server for breakage

Comment: So I guess the new error I'm getting as depicted in https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nz5o.png is due to a plugin. `php artisan plugin:install Axmit.Storage` is being done after `composer update`. How can I tell OctoberCMS to use a newer version of the plugin?

Comment: https://octobercms.com/plugin/axmit-storage is the link to the plugin. Looks like the last release was in 2017 so I'm most likely stuck on 1.0.443...

Comment: You don't need that plugin anymore. See https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#database-driven-themes, that feature is now built right into the core as `cms.databaseTemplates`. You just need to follow the instructions at https://github.com/octoberrain/meta/blob/master/l6-upgrade-notes.md (but just use the composer.json lines from https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/develop/composer.json#L33-L47) and then you should be able to upgrade no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the OctoberCMS version according to the instructions on the official OctoberCMS website

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me _how_ to properly upgrade. My composer.json currently has 1.0.443 for october/rain, october/system, october/backend and october/cms. Since it's requiring a specific version `composer update` won't work. I tried changing that to 1.0.460 and then doing `composer update` but now I'm getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nz5o.png . v1.1 won't work because it requires PHP 7.2 and this server is running 7.1. All I want to do is update an address via the UI. I don't want to spend a week upgrading the whole server and then testing every app on the server for breakage

Comment: I guess there's another reason I can't use the latest OctoberCMS version - the website is using https://octobercms.com/plugin/axmit-storage which had it's last release in 2017...